# UIActivityViewController in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios10

Anyone know how to use UIActivityView in iOS 10? Now that for some reason in Swift 3.0 it will compile and build but when the application is running after pressing a share button using the following code results in an application crash... it worked perfectly in iOS 9.3 and Swift 2.0.

As specified in the comments of the code line 6 or `let objectsToShare = [textToShare] as! AnyObject` causes a Thread1: signal SIGABRT and application crash

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UITextView!

@IBAction func share(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let textToShare = detailDescriptionLabel.attributedText

        let objectsToShare = [textToShare] as! AnyObject
        // line above causes app crash in iOS 10 - compiled and built
        // error is "Thread1: signal SIGABRT"

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as! [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIView)
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


class ActivityForNotesViewController: UIActivityViewController {

    internal func _shouldExcludeActivityType(_ activity: UIActivity) -> Bool {
        let activityTypesToExclude = [
            //insert UIActivity here
        ]

        if let actType = activity.activityType {
            if activityTypesToExclude.contains(actType) {
                return true
            }
            else if super.excludedActivityTypes != nil {
                return super.excludedActivityTypes!.contains(actType)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Anyone that can help me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you cast array to AnyObject. That does not make much sense.

Comment: @Andy I'm not too sure why I did end up actually doing it. For some reason though when I remove that text from the code the compiler complains. it does make sense and is more efficient to not make the cast but I'm not 100% about how else to make it work without it.

Comment: If I had to guess it would be because the function `UIActivityViewController(activityItems:`uses a cast in the decleration of the function here `objectsToShare as! [AnyObject]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have answered my own question, but if someone can double check I'd appreciate it. The comments in the code are the various changes that I made to get this fix to work. Works in iOS 10 in Simulator and a real device.

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // Changed attributedText to text!
        let textToShare = detailDescriptionLabel.text!

        // Removed Cast to AnyObject
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare]

        //Removed cast to AnyObject in the Function Call to get rid of error from removing it above
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare , applicationActivities: nil)


//Moved cast for as! UIView outside the perantheses of sender so 
//that the as! can be used more efficiently. But most importantly
// I changed the as! to a as? instead thinking that might catch an error and it did... so this works.

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender) as? UIView
                self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let objectsToShare = [textToShare]

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
```

Should be the way to use it.